# How to understand the Camera's memory requirement in Android L CCD ？

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-compatibility

In android L ccd, there is a item as the following:

7.5 Cameras

Memory

- [NEW] If a device implementation includes at least one camera, it SHOULD be possible for an application to simultaneously allocate 3 bitmaps equal to the size of the images produced by the largest-resolution camera sensor on the device.

**Why it shall allow app to allocate 3 bitmaps size equal to images produced by the largest resolution camera sensor ?**

Comment: The only people who can definitely state "why" work for Google and are unlikely to comment here. You might consider [the `android-compatibility` Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-compatibility) or perhaps one of [the other AOSP Google Groups](http://source.android.com/source/community/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare . It's so helpful for me. If there are some guys can answer the question, that will be great!

Comment: I had posted the question about 7 days ago, but there wasn't any answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-compatibility/B5QFuU7OVrE